# Can both male and female have their nikkah without their parents knowing but later informing everyone and have a wedding?

Tags: nikah, wedding

As-salamu alaykum,

I am curious to know whether the marriage would be valid if the couple were to go off and have their nikkah with an imaam without any approval from parents on both sides.

Back story:
I (female) am not ready to tell my parents about getting married as the person I want to get married too is not stable enough and has only just graduated from university however I do know my parents will give their approval

He knows his parents will not accept the marriage as it will be an interracial marriage therefore wants to make sure he is financially stable and has his own place before telling his parents as he knows they will kick him out.

If we was to get have a nikkah without telling both our families would it be valid and then later on telling our parents and having a wedding to make it “official” to everyone else

Comment: The permission of the Wali (in most cases the father) of the bride is a requirement for valid Nikah according to the majority opinion, as the Prophet [said](https://sunnah.com/ibnmajah:1880): لا نكاح إلا بولي  ‏ This should already be covered extensively on this website and other places on the internet. Please put effort into researching for yourself before asking.

Answer (score 0):

The presence of wali in Nikah is one of the necessary conditions that cannot be ignored. So if a marriage contract is held without the wali of woman, then it cannot be considered as a fulfilled Nikah and will be rendered as null or void.

Allaah’s Messenger (ﷺ) said: “**There is no marriage except with a guardian**.”
Ahmad, 19518. Abu Dawood, 2085. Ibn Maajah, 1881. At-Tirmidhee, 1101. Ibn Hibbaan, 4077

Also, it is reported by Imaam Ahmad from Hasan, from Imrān Ibn Husayn ascribed to Allaah Messenger (ﷺ) that he said:
“**There is no marriage except with a guardian and two witnesses**.”
At-Tabaraanee in “Al-Kabeer” 19/299. Ad-Daaruqutnee, 1101. Al-Bayhaqee, 7/125

Answer (score 0):

If your parents give approval, why would you not tell them? The bride’s wali (her father if he is alive) must give permission for a valid nikah.

Even from a practical standpoint, I think it would be a far worse situation to spring it on your parents that “I’m married” versus asking them permission beforehand, especially if you expect them to approve.